# How to detect if a message is edited?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am intending for my bot to allow only "ew" to be sent in chat. I have resolved majority of the work-arounds, however, there is one I can't resolve independently. When someone posts "ew" in chat and then edits the message to something else, it remains like that without being deleted.

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`client.on('messageUpdate')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate) should trigger everytime a message (in cache) is edited. I'm pretty sure you will not get the event if the message was sent when the bot was offline. But you could fetch the messages when the bot starts.

```
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
   if(newMessage.content != "ew"){
       newMessage.delete(); // for example
   }
})
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm unsure how to delete the message. How could I do that?

Comment: `newMessage.delete()` ?

Comment: Well as I said, it only works for cached message. So try turning on the bot, send a message and then edit it.

Comment: @BrandonB Make sure your bot has the "Manage Messages" permission.

Comment: @André is there anyway to make this work with partials so even after restarting, it works?